# How to update the React Native application's performance?

Tags: android, reactjs, performance, react-native, performance-testing

I am trying to make a react native application in IoT using MQTT. I get constant updates of data every 500 milliseconds and I have to update the state variable. The whole process is hurting the application's performance. On some lower end phones, the UI feels clunky or the application itself hangs. Is there a way to improve it's performance?

Comment: If you update the state variable it automatically triggers a render. Perhaps you can enable conditional rendering based on a time variable. That might help.

Comment: Yeah I suppose.Thanks for the suggestion!!

Comment: Is there a way in this where redux can be used to improve performance?

Comment: You may also use 'this' to store the data instead of a state variable and refer to this variable whenever you want to render.

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/where-do-i-belong-a-guide-to-saving-react-component-data-in-state-store-static-and-this-c49b335e2a00/ this explains all about variables. Should help you solve it. My comment previously(on this) is also redux oriented

Comment: You can use shouldComponentUpdate to provide info if re render should occur.Also you can move the not changing parts to separate components.

Comment: I think this should help the performance a lot @ThakurKarthik

Comment: @ThakurKarthik Whenever I use nextState.val it is showing that to be undefined. I don't understand. Can you please help me out?

Comment: create a reproducible link in expo